# My MSK Connector is stuck in Creating state due to misconfiguration. Is there a way to delete it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-msk

I have setup a MSK connector falsly with misconfigurations in the connector configuration and now it is stuck in Creating state. I am trying to delete it to create a new one but it is not allowing me to edit its configuration or delete it since it is in Creating state. Is there an indirect way of solving this issue ?

Thanks in advance.
[Status of MSK Connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F233R.png)

I tried changing the configuration but it is not allowing me to change it since it is in Creating state.
I haven't tried the CLI since I am using an internal instance of AWS CLI related to my company and it does not have the delete-connector flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that deleting a MSK connector is not yet supported by AWS.

> "Unfortunately it is not possible to delete a worker configuration from MSK Connect, but according to a MSK team member, the capability is on the roadmap without a definite timeline." - Mikel Del Tio

https://repost.aws/questions/QUr4E3YzGSTry3qvh_xeV_jQ/how-to-delete-msk-worker-configurations

I ended up waiting for the status to change and adjusted the configurations.